# Resources to learn about spontaneous parametric down conversion

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

I have recently begun working on a project where I will be modeling some experiment that uses SPDC to generate entanglement. However, I have not formally studied SPDC in any capacity. Is there any reputable resource I can learn (textbook, online lecture notes, etc..) where I can learn more about this process? A quick google search led me to a relatively bare Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better suited for a comment, but I cannot post one. Have you found [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00127) resource? It appears to contain theoretical background, but I cannot judge if it is appropriate for your situation.